# How to use proxy server to use firebase auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So here's situation,

The firebase auth is very good.

But in some area for some reason the host of `https://www.googleapis.com` are `not accessible` from app side.

So I was think about a way to proxy the request to `https://www.googleapis.com` in may iOS app to `My Server`, and `My Server` will `transfer` the `auth request` to `https://www.googleapis.com` on server sider.

#### Question

Is there a way to config the `host` in firebase API ? Or is this a good way to do it?

Comment: unfortunately no.